# python could not get verified after installation

Tags: python

can anyone help me downloading python in windows 10? it saying it is downloaded but could not get verified and I can not locate the file especially the exe. thats when I can not add it to path. please help. thanks

try everything but did not work, watched bunch of videos, followed the instructions etc.

Comment: Please be clear, whether the downloaded file is gone or the Installation in gone.